# AWS Cross Region application code deployment

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am a student and learning aws.

I have codecommit created in N.Virginia region and the EC2 instance is created in N.California region.

I have created codepipeline to deploy sample app to N.Viriginia EC2 instance and it works fine.

How do I wire codecommit to pipeline so that it can deploy to N.California?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS CodePipeline supports cross-region deployment, you can deploy your application across multiple regions from a single pipeline. Please see the following [link:](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-aws-codepipeline-to-perform-multi-region-deployments/)
You can use AWS CodeCommit as source control.